# How to convert RPM with dependencies to DEB package

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rpm, deb, alien

I am trying to convert my RPM file to a DEB file.
RPM file has post and pre-run scripts and some dependencies.
I am using alien to convert the rpm file to deb:

```
sudo alien -c ./mypackage.rpm
```

I am able to convert this rpm to deb file. But, if I check the dependencies using:

```
dpkg -I ./mypackage.deb
```

I am not able to see any Depends section. I tried installing the deb file, but it did not install any of the dependencies.